# Why do I have to do a setenforce 0 to cluster tomcat on Scientific Linux using mod_proxy

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, mod-proxy, selinux

Why do I have to do a setenforce 0 to cluster tomcat on Scientific Linux using mod_proxy

I am using Scientific Linux release 6.2 and trying to get mod_proxy working with httpd and tomcat.

I want to have two tomcat nodes running on the box and so I need to change the 2nd tomcat node ajp port to something diff then 8009 like 8109, But once I change the port on Scientific Linux it stops working but I have found if I do a

**setenforce 0**

it works then.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing and if anyone knows a better what to get tomcat nodes working on  Scientific Linux without doing a setenforce 0

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you make 'setenforce 0' you disable SELinux enforcing mode. It means, there are no real denials in your system, just it is logged for debuging.

There are just SELInux rules for common configurations. You have to allow tomcat to run on a different port and also you have to enable httpd server to connect that port.

Read more about binding in connecting ports and SELinux on http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/9275.html